# Using sed to split strings of varying length (GPS coordinates)

Tags: string, sed

I am trying to split gps coordinates into two separate fields in a CSV file. The coordinates are currently combined. Here is a few examples:

```
+40.71427-074.00597/
-42+174/
+33.20984-087.56917/
+39.76-098.5/
+39.76-098.5/
+42.27756-083.74088/
```

I was thinking of splitting this using: 
`sed -r 's/-/,-/g'`

but this would only work for the strings that contain a "-", some of these begin the string with a - or have a + in the middle. The +/- signs are important to keep as they determine direction, so I cannot afford to lose them.

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated and thank you for taking the time!

Comment: Try `sed -E 's/(.+)([-+])/\1,\2/'`

Comment: [edit] your question to show the expected output given that input.

Comment: Does [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55583077/3832970) help? Please let know if there is anything else that is unclear about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With any sed:

```
$ sed 's:\(.*\)\([+-].*\)/:\1,\2:' file
+40.71427,-074.00597
-42,+174
+33.20984,-087.56917
+39.76,-098.5
+39.76,-098.5
+42.27756,-083.74088
```

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[+-]/,&/2' file
```

This replaces the second occurrence of either `+` or `-` by `,+` or `,-`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
sed -E 's/(.+)([-+])/\1,\2/'  file > newfile # POSIX ERE syntax
sed 's/\(.*\)\([-+]\)/\1,\2/' file > newfile # POSIX BRE syntax
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/yDWS5w)

The `(.+)([-+])` pattern matches and captures into Group 1 any one or more chars and then captures a `-` or `+` in Group 2 and then `\1,\2` replacement inserts a comma in between the groups.

You may make the pattern a bit more efficient with a negated bracket expression:

```
's/([^-+]+)([-+])/\1,\2/' # POSIX ERE
's/\([^-+]*\)\([-+]\)/\1,\2/' # POSIX BRE
```

where `[^-+]+` matches 1 or more chars other than `-` and `+`.